# Why is part of my UIView covering the keyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, keyboard

Part of my UIView is covering the iPad's keyboard.

[image]

The view you're seeing is simply a UIView I've added as a subview to my main view. When the keyboard is shown, I do shift the view up.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

**EDIT**

When the keyboard is shown, I move the view up:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:SHOW_KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.currentViewController.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y -= SHOW_KEYBOARD_OFFSET;

    self.currentViewController.view.frame = frame;
}];
```

**EDIT**

I use the follow code to add the view:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:fromView toView:toView duration:0.3f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:nil];
```

Comment: Wow... That shouldn't happen.  The keyboard is in its own UIWindow...

Comment: Yeah. It's really strange. I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: What do you do to make the keyboard appear ? Do you click on a UITextField ?

Comment: Yes. I click on a UITextField, contained inside a UITableViewCell. Because the keyboard would cover the text field, I move the view up when the keyboard appears.

Comment: can you post the code you use to move the view?  it's easy to make the mistake where you shift something down instead of up, especially if you're used to working in another UI framework where the origin isn't at top left.

Comment: If you can easily reproduce the problem I think you should file a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @Nate: I've updated the question to include the code I use to move the view.

Comment: And you're confident that the value of SHOW_KEYBOARD_OFFSET is right (correct sign, and sufficient magnitude)?  You've tried changing the value of that constant?  And what do you see?  Always the same overlap?  Something else ...

Comment: Is this happening on the simulator and on the device?

Comment: Both. It's worse on the simulator but also occurs on the device.

Comment: can you post the code you used to add the subview?

Comment: @ThEuSeFuL I added it into the question. See the second edit.

Comment: @QuentonJones, when you use that code toView is added to fromView.superview, fromView is removed from its superview. Please make sure that fromView.superview is self.currentViewController.view

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the code to move the view out of the way before or after the keyboard is displayed?  In other words, are you registering for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification or UIKeyboardDidShowNotification?

I'm not sure where you are getting the keyboard size?  Take a look at Apple's sample code again, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html, scroll down to the section on moving content that is located under the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting SHOW_KEYBOARD_OFFSET from? I bet that's the problem.

You should be catching the notifications, just as Kate said, and using the userInfo from them to work out what to do about moving your view around. Any hard coded values will break the second Apple change the keyboard size on you. In short, don't assume what the frameworks can so easily tell you.